# jQuery Parse JSON Response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am successfully Posting to a PHP file, and getting a good response. The part I cannot seem to get is parsing it out then displaying it on my page. Here is my javascript in a validate handler:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    $.post('http://test.php', formData, function(data) {
        if(data.success) {
            $('#load').show();
            var response = i;
            $('#load').hide();
            //var msg = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < x.flights.length; i++) {
               msg += '<span>';
               msg += '<p>Flight Number: ' + x.flights[i].flight_number + '</p>';
               msg += '<p>Cost: ' + x.flights[i].cost + '</p>';
               msg += '</span>';
            }
            //this is were I think it should display. but It's not working

            $('#load').html(msg);
```

Here is my json response:

```
   success
true

 message
"Success"

flights
[Object { flight_number="334", cost="983.40", departure_city="Kearney Regional Airpor...arney, Nebraska - (EAR)", more...}]

0
Object { flight_number="334", cost="983.40", departure_city="Kearney Regional Airpor...arney, Nebraska - (EAR)", more...}

flight_number
"334"

cost
"983.40"

departure_city
"Kearney Regional Airport, Kearney, Nebraska - (EAR)"

arrival_city
"Chadron Muni Airport, Chadron, Nebraska - (CDR)"

departs
"2014-03-19 04:33:00"

arrives
"2014-03-19 08:12:00"

duration
"219"

adult_seats_available
"2"

senior_seats_available
"1"
```

I know you you are not seeing the JSON response, but I can see it in FF firebug. I'm new to jQuery/JSON, and I just want to print the response to my page. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#load').show();
                var response = i;
                $('#load').hide();
                //var msg = '';`?

Comment: Make $('#load').show(). Currently it is hidden.

Comment: post your json response

Comment: It's for a loading .gif that I'm using while the server responds to the request.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `JSON.stringify(data)` [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) I don't know where you want to display your JSON but if you just want to see what it is open up the debugger and `console.log(JSON.stringify(data));` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are using post method and it may default return xml, json, script, text, html. So you are getting the data from post method.

Try looking at https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

And if you want to access it, then you can use JSON.stringify(data) to show json as a string. And to access data from json you can use dot(.) notation.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things to look at here.

First you're adding your html (ie `msg`) to the `#load` element (`$('#load').html(msg);`) but earlier in the code you're hiding it (`$('#load').hide();`). So I think this will answer your main question; i.e. remove the the line `$('#load').hide();` or add `$('#load').show();` after the line `$('#load').html(msg);`.

Still not seeing anything? Then perhaps the response isn't as corrent as you're claiming so perhaps an easier way to check what's been assigned to `msg` is to alert the html `alert(msg);` <- make this call after you've built your html.

So aside from this is the use of the `#load` element you seem to be using it to hold a loading gif but also assigning it the response via the content of `msg`. Perhaps you need to separate the use of the elements so that the `#load` element is for the loading gif and you add another element for the response. so you're code is more like this.

**html**

```
<div id="load" class="hide"><img src="loading-animation.gif">...</div>
<div id="post-response" class="hide alert"><div>
```

where the *hide* class is *display none* and *alert* class represents an style for a response alert.

**js**

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    // show the loading gif before we make the 
    // post data and wait for an async response
    $('#load').show();

    ...
    $.post('http://test.php', formData, function(data) {
        if(data.success) {

            // post-back has completed so lets hide the animation
            $('#load').hide();

            // your code to build html msg

            // assign and show the response element
            $('post-response').html(msg);
            $('post-response').show();
            ...
```

Comment: Hi Chris,

I tried to print the response with the alert, but that did not seem to work. I know the response is working correctly because I can see in Firebug the JSON response.

I seem to have a disconnect on how to display this to the page.

Comment: Sorry not sure what else to suggest - it would seem something else is causing a problem. At this point you need to make sure you know how to debug javascript (in Firefox) using the dev tools - I suggest using the `debugger` keyword and adding as the first line of the callback function. What happens if you remove all the code except something simple that only alerts the response? Like this.
`submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.post('http://test.php', formData, function(data, status) {
        alert("Status: " + status + "\n\nData: " + data);
    }
}`

Comment: I was able to get it to open the parsed response in alert with:

alert(data.flights[0].arrival_city);